# Botão editar, deletar em uma lista feita em HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu sei que é muito mais fácil utilizar framesworks e tecnologias específicas para desenvolvimento web como Angular.JS, ZEND, Java EE, etc. Mas estou desenvolvendo um sistema CRUD utilizando o minimo de "facilidades" possíveis.

Para um sistema utilizando somente linguagens de programação Javascript e PHP
qual seria a melhor prática para associar o botão Editar e Deletar ao seu registro correspondente?
Tive a ideia de colocar uma coluna de Código na tela de listagem para cada registro, e assim ao clicar em um dos botões, pega-se o código do registro que esta na mesma linha da TABLE do HTML(utilizando JS), mas essa seria uma boa prática? teria outras maneiras de fazer isso?

[image: CRUD]

Comment: Pode colocar o `value="id do registro"` no botão, sendo assim pode recuperar esse value pelo JavaScript. Alguns programadores também colocam um link no botão de uma página que está esperando o `id` pelo método `get`, o link ficaria assim: `suaPagina.php?id=*id do registro*`.

Comment: Depende de algumas coisas; por exemplo, pra onde você quer enviar o código ao clicar em "edit" e "delete"? Vai enviar pra uma função? Enviar pra outra página?

Comment: O ideal seria trazer os registros atraves de um select se estas informações forem ligadas a um banco de dados e o botão editar ser ligado a um comando update tanto como o deletar ser ligado ao comando delete

Comment: @ÐvÐ vai mandar para um arquivo .php, que conterá uma função responsável por executar um DELETE no banco de dados.

Comment: Mas isso é via Ajax ou vai fazer um redirecionamento? Você pode colocar o código de cada registro diretamente no botão, sem ter que usar JS pra isso, não?

Comment: Pretendo fazer um redirecionamento. Eu não tive essa ideia de gerar os botões com um value atrelado ao código no banco de dados, já mencionando pelo @LaércioLopes.